# how to force WebAPI in MVC4 to render null strings as empty in json result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How to render null string properties as empty strings in ASP.NET MVC4 Web API v.1 in json result?
WebAPI renders them as

```
"myproperty": null
```

how to render this as

```
"myproperty": ""
```

controller is

```
public class Customer {
   public string myproperty { get; set; }
   }

    public class CustomersController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var cust = new Customer();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
               new { customers = cust.ToArray() });
        }
     }
```

object are nested and contain lot of string properties. Setting them all to empty strings in constructor seems ugly. API caller needs empty strings or 0 for decimals, it does not like null constant in any value.

Comment: That's a completely ridiculous requirement. Null and empty strings are 2 completely different notions and are JSON serialized differently. Why would you want to mix those notions? You could of course achieve that by writing a custom ValueProvider for JSON.NET but I don't even want to show an example of that as this seems completely useless thing to do. And most importantly a very wrong thing to do.

Comment: What's the reason about judging requirements? He wants null string to be treated as empty strings, that's it. We don't have enough contest to say if it's good or not. You don't like it? Care.

Comment: Just mentioning that those requirements do not make any reasonable sense. Sometimes people are forced to write completely stupid and wrong code just because they are obeying requirements that are completely ridiculous. Instead of explaining the people that enforced those requirements how wrong they are. That's usually how we end up with hacks and completely crapped up software.

Comment: Or maybe he is experimenting and just having fun, or he needs to comply to some system he cannot change. We just don't know it.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to point that out so that other people stumbling upon this question do not make the same mistake. It's a good thing to experiment, it's another thing to write real world code. We are all having fun at times :-)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I need to create api for existing javascript application. I looked into existing response and all unassigned string values contain empty strings. Currently my API returns null values but application does not work correctly. So I thought to try empty strings like existing API provides to it. Javascript application is complex and difficult to understand or refactor.

Comment: I would go try to fix that javascript instead of writing yet another piece of code that's eligible for http://thedailywtf.com/ I understand that sometimes there are things that make us write crappy code, but let's do something about it and attack the root cause of the problem instead of contributing to the world with more bad code to maintain. Don't get me wrong, I am just mentioning that so that other people coming upon this question do not make the same mistake as you. Don't forget that SO is a pretty well referenced web site on Google and there might be other users with the same problem.

Comment: @Geeo I just wanted to try empty strings. I'm not sure that this is the cause but since original server api passes always empty strings I thought that there is simple setting like Json.NET has. There are 30 properties and nested objects. Geeo answer requires write if statement for every property which is lot of work. So I asked for some global setting.

Comment: You may want follow @DarinDimitrov's suggestion and implement your ValueProvider

Comment: My 2cents on the issue: When you are dealing with APIs, you have no control over  existing clients (so fix the client javascript is mostly not an option), while backward compatibility is really important and should be enforced. Setting default values for properties is not a hack nor crappy, that's why there's an implementation to do it within the framework without writing our own value providers or 'hacky' code. I still agree that it's better if can be avoided on, for example, new developments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can decorate your properties like this :

```
[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
[DefaultValue("")]
public string myproperty{ get; set; }
```

Note that you can set the default value handling to populate in a global config like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration
.Configuration
.Formatters
.JsonFormatter
.SerializerSettings
.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
```

So, you don't need to decorate it to every property. You will only need to use the `DefaultValue`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Customer {
   private string _myproperty = String.Empty;
   public string myproperty 
   { 
      get { return _myproperty; }; 
      set { _myproperty = value ?? String.Empty; } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually there are 30 properties from which some are assigned with null values. Using your answer requires to write if statement for every property before return. Maybe it is possible to create value provider which converts null to empty string and pass it to CreateResponse method to use it or use JSon.NET or other serializer which allows this ?

Answer (score 0):

i give little overhead but solve my problem

```
DataTable dt = (new tst()).Gettable();
            string s = string.Empty;
            s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
           s= s.Replace("null", "\"\"");
            Object obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
            return Ok(obj);
```

Answer (score -7):

As default web api works like this...
you don't need to change

Comment: It does not work like this. As described in question, it renders null string values as null in json